# Color schemes for WPF apps

Tags: wpf, user-interface, colors

Is there any good articles or guidelines for color schemes for desktop applications? I am specifically interested in WPF based apps, but any good practices will do. Keep in mind the target should be for the artistically challenged...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN has a bit to say about that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742482.aspx). I do not think there is anything about WPF which warrants specialized guidelines.

Comment: Link is no longer active.